# Using an IF() based on a query result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying  to use an IF() is mySQL where the structure looks something like this:

```
if(
phone_number LIKE '%992%' (SELECT phone_number FROM db.phonebook WHERE country='UK'),
SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE xxx,
SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE xxx
)
```

I'm trying to achieve:

```
IF   (if you manage to find a phone number in the 'UK' phonebook that looks like '992'),
THEN (run the following XXX query),
ELSE (run the following YYY query)
```

This doesn't work, the syntax is obviously wrong.
Would appreciate you advice.

Comment: Do it in your programming language with 2 queries

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything like that via a query - you can do this using a procedure - but you can't return a resultset from a query (you can return a string which might contain a query).

But it's not clear where 'phone_number' somes from before you've actually selected anything from the database.

Perhaps if you told us explicitly what queries you wanted to run on the 2 possible scenarios and where phone_number comes from when we might be able to help.